# flash develop plugin

Tags: apache-flex, plugins, actionscript, flashdevelop

I have been using flex builder plug-in. But now trial period has expired and looking for some other option which comes free. I am trying to install flash develop plugin for eclipse. In my attempt to install I am trying this page but donno what all plugins to install...http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=3rd_Party_Plugins  ...Can some one please guide. The problem i am facing here is I am not sure about what is outdated and what is useful

Answer (score 2):

FlashDevelop is a standalone application (windows only), as far I know there is no plugin for eclipse. If you are searching for an eclipse plugin, there's the commercial [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/), with a 30 day trial period.

A new FlashDevelop version (4.0) is about to be released and most plugins from the old version aren't compatible with the new one. So I unless there's a new list somewhere or some plugin explicitly states that it supports the new version, every plugin there is probably outdated. Anyway, many plugins from that list have been integrated in FlashDevelop. You can of course use the latests stable 3.x version if you need a particular plugin.

If you've never used FlashDevelop, you should just try the [stable 3.3.4 or the latest 4.0 beta](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewforum.php?f=11) or the [very latest developement build](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3529) and see if you are missing some features.

Comment: FlashDevelop is hands down the best IDE I've used for Flash. FDT might be good, but anything built on Eclipse is precrippled

Comment: divillysausages, FlashDevelop is the worst IDE I've used for Flash. It's buggy and limited in functionality. Eclipse provide much more useful features, more control over code and IDE itself. So don't be so flat, every man to his taste.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your code in Notepad and use the command line compiler provided in the free SDK.  It's not going to be as nice as any IDE, but it is functional.

Another option, if you are a student or unemployed, is to [request a complimentary license to Flash Builder from Adobe](https://freeriatools.adobe.com/).

Another option is to use [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml), a Free Visual Studio Plugin for Flex Development.  However, you'll need Visual Studio for that to work.  [And I assume a Windows Machine].

FlashDevelop, as others have noted, is not an Eclipse Plugin as far as I knew.  It is a stand alone tool.

Other IDEs for building Flex applications are:

1. [Sapphire Steel Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/), which is a commercial Visual Studio
   Plugin
2. [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/); which is an eclipse based plugin.  I believe FDT5
       will have a free / community option, but I do not know if it is
       available yet.
3. [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which many developers swear by.

And of course Flash Builder.  I believe the previous three are all commercial plugins, so do not fill your "free" Criteria.

Comment: thanks a lot for your guidance .. I am currently working on a mavenized java project which is using Spring + flex through AMF Remoting. I am already having everything set-up in my eclipse IDE so it will be nice if i can survive using the same. I want to explore all my options before switching to Intellij. Also, I guess switching to visual studio is out of question( as i am working with maven). I am feeling sad about expiration of plug-in. I have applied for complimentary license which I will only get after two weeks. Currently struggling with note-pad and command line. I can't afford $299.

Comment: Why does the use of Maven prevent you from using Visual Studio?

Comment: sorry its my mistake.. I am a new user and I thought visual studio doesn't provide Maven support. I am currently trying option provided by Kapep. i.e installing flash develop plug-in . The warning mentioned there is bit scary. "You'll lose your settings:
Expect these builds to be incompatible with existing & future application settings. Backup all your setting files as this version might wipe out you existing settings." Does this warning means I will loose whole set-up I am currently having :( PLEASE PROVIDE YOUR VIEWs ON USING FLASH DEVELOP.

Comment: I never used FlashDevelop and know very little about it despite the fact that it is well regarded.  Best of luck!

Comment: @anupam that just means you can lose your previous *FlashDevelop settings*. That warning really seems a bit scary, but I've never had any problems with it. You don't need to configure anything to get started. Btw I use FlashDevelop because of its good haXe support, I've only done only a few AS things with it but I think it is a very good IDE for it.